# Delphi Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7, with Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 32 bit OS.

My issue is I unable to detect my outlook is running or not.
I tried the following code.

```
uses
  ComObj, ActiveX;

function IsObjectActive(ClassName: string): Boolean;
var
  ClassID: TCLSID;
  Unknown: IUnknown;
begin
  try
    ClassID := ProgIDToClassID(ClassName);
    Result  := GetActiveObject(ClassID, nil, Unknown) = S_OK;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsObjectActive('Outlook.Application') then ShowMessage('Outlook is running !');
end;
```

Using the above code, delphi is not detecting the Outlook is running.

Can you tell me is there any good alternative way for the same. In my application I am using Outlook Redemption, so is there anything in Redemption, so that I can detect outlook is running?

Comment: I would guess you are running either Delphi (an thus your program) or Outlook with elevated privileges? I can replicate the problem when running Delphi as administrator, not when running normally.

Comment: In case you are not running with different acounts/elevation levels... In the example above, did you just _start_ Outlook? Outlook doesn't register itself into the Running Object Table (as queried by getActiveObject) until there has been a focus switch.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if outlook.exe process is running.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this help.

```
library IsCra;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Windows,
  TlHelp32;

{$R *.res}

function AppIsRunning(AApp: String): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  h: THandle;
  p: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := False;

  p.dwSize := SizeOf(p);
  h := CreateToolHelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SnapProcess, 0);
  try
    Process32First(h, p);
    repeat
      Result := AnsiUpperCase(AApp) = AnsiUpperCase(p.szExeFile);
    until Result or (not Process32Next(h, p));
  finally
    CloseHandle(h);
  end;
end;

exports
  AppIsRunning;

begin
end.
```

Comment: I don't think the OP would need the "dll project" format you've used here.   Change "library" to "unit", and remove the exports, and the "begin" immediately before the end, and add the interface and implementation keywords, and you would have a valid unit that can be included into your own code. Posting a standalone compileable DLL demo is probably less than ideal.

Comment: I hope that the most people copy the function and drop it in there code. I use this dll for inno setup to know if the application is running before new installation.